# Finding all elements of a group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be a group of all bijection from $f:\mathbb{R}- \{0,1,-1\}\to\mathbb{R}- \{0,1,-1\}$.

let $g(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$

$c)$ let $H$ be a subgroup of $F$ which is generated by the set  $\{g(x),\frac{1}{x}\}$

Find all elements of $H$ and the dimension of a real vector space generated by the elements of the set $H$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

The elements generated by $g(x)$ are $\frac{1+x}{1-x},\,-\frac{1}{x},\,\frac{1-x}{1+x},\,x\,$ and by $H$ are $ \frac{1}{x},\,x$

However I am not sure how to continue from here. Do I  have to check all possible combinations and their inverses (taking into account that composition is not commutative) and hope that I can spot some pattern?

I would really appreciate it if somebody could explain to me the procces of find all the elements of a group given a generator set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* A function of the form $f(x) = \frac{a x + b}{c x + d}$ is called a linear fractional transformation and can be represented by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. The composition of two linear fractional transformations is represented by the product of their matrices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :
so my problem now becomes finding all elements of a group generated matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ Do I now  have to calculate  all the possible combination of products between these two matrices?

Comment: @westlife Nah, you already know that $g^4=1$ and $f^2=1$. Now observe that $fgfg=1$ and thus $H$ is the Dihedral group $D_4$. Hence it has exactly $8$ elements: $H=\{1,g,g^2,g^3,f,fg,fg^2,fg^3\}$. All that is left is to show how big $\mathbb{R}H$ is. This requires some calculations since the dimension is at most $4$.

Comment: Oh yeah now that you've spelled it out for me the solution is pretty obvious. However I don't believe I would ever do that conclusion by myself

Thank you both for helping